# How to do "netcat" relays properly so that I have more control?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, networking, tcp

How to use the `netcat` to have relays? Like following I tried but not working:

```
cd /tmp
mknod backpipe p
nc -l -p 7007 0<backpipe | nc 192.168.1.101 9001 | tee backpipe
```

1. I want to receive data on 7007 must be listening mode
   $ another application is putting packets here
2. what ever comes to 7007 I need to move to 9001 (which is also a listening port)

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 9001
   ```

   will show 7007 packets?

Any idea?

Optional: will it be also possible that I can put some extra header packets? to simulate http headers as image content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
nc -l -p 7007 | nc -l -p 9001
```

Then anything that comes in to port 7007 will be piped to the second netcat and be relayed to your telnet session on port 9001.

Injecting headers requires knowing the underlying protocol, at least to figure out "message" boundaries, so it's not trivial. If you know how to do it, you can inject your code to do so between the two pipes:

```
nc -l -p 7007 | ./my_filter | nc -l -p 9001
```

`./my_filter` will get the input on `stdin`, and anything it writes to `stdout` will show up on port 9001.

Comment: The first line opens, but when i connect i get this: nc: connect to 192.168.1.101 port 9001 (tcp) failed: No route to host

Comment: The lines I posted all listen on `localhost`, they don't try to open sockets to remote hosts. I don't see how you could get that error with what I posted.

Comment: Second command fails, 7007 is not able to connect. e.g: nc -l 7007 | ./my_filter | nc -l 9001

Comment: ./my_filter is a bash file trying to get stdin.

Comment: Make sure you don't have something else (or the previous command) already listening on that socket.

Comment: if i do this then it fail e.g: $ nc -l 7007 | printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\nContent-Type: video/webm\r\n\r\n" | nc -l 9001

Comment: Yes, it will fail. `printf` doesn't expect input on stdin.